# Python sort list by another list, but the sorting one is a date type

Tags: python, list, sorting, matplotlib, time

I am trying to sort a list by another one but the sorting one is in date format: `%H:%M:%S`.

The goal is to create a matplotlib bar graph (no problem on that part).

I know that I can sort the date type one by using:

```
from datetime import datetime
a = ['0:11:40', '0:10:20', '1:11:10']
a.sort(key=lambda date: datetime.strptime(date, "%H:%M:%S"))
```

And I also know that I can sort a list by another one by using the `zip` function.

But I need to accomplish both of them:

- `listA`: type `%H:%M:%S`
- `listB`: string
- `listC`: string

Example:

```
listA = ['0:11:40', '0:10:20', '1:11:10']
listB = ['team B', 'team A', 'team C']
listC = ['rgb(255,100,100)','rgb(100,125,125)', 'rgb(125,255,255)']
```

My idea would be:

`%H:%M:%S` format → int (seconds)

So I could sort the list as an list of integer (`zip` with `listB` and `listC`), and then go back to `%H:%M:%S` format to show on top of the bar (plt.text: no issue on that part).

But is there any other "cleaner" method to do so?

Comment: Why not keep using `strptime` to convert `%H:%M:%S` formatted date strings into something sortable?

Comment: As i was saying, i could convert it to `%S` and then to `int` so i can use the zip function. But isn't it to heavy, can we find a "better" solution for this problem ?

Comment: What is the expected output here?

Comment: What prevents you from using the zip function when you don't convert the dates to integers?

Comment: `listA, listB, listC = zip(*sorted(zip(listA, listB, listC), key=lambda o: datetime.strptime(o[0], "%H:%M:%S")))`

Comment: The expected output is : the 3 lists sorted by the lowest time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use simple one-liner:

```
listA, listB, listC = zip(*sorted(zip(listA, listB, listC), key=lambda o: datetime.strptime(o[0], "%H:%M:%S")))
```

Comment: Great answer, Thanks

Comment: @SydneyR, please notice that after execution `listA`, `listB` and `listC` will be tuples, not lists. To convert them to lists you can use `map(list, ...)` *if needed ofc*.

Answer (score 0):

Use `zip` and `sorted`:

```
srt = sorted(zip(listA, listB, listC), key=lambda x:datetime.strptime(x[0], "%H:%M:%S"))
rvs = list(zip(*srt))
```

Output:

```
srt
# [('0:10:20', 'team A', 'rgb(100,125,125)'),
#  ('0:11:40', 'team B', 'rgb(255,100,100)'),
#  ('1:11:10', 'team C', 'rgb(125,255,255)')]

rvs
#[('0:10:20', '0:11:40', '1:11:10'),
# ('team A', 'team B', 'team C'),
# ('rgb(100,125,125)', 'rgb(255,100,100)', 'rgb(125,255,255)')]
```